# Push notification for Google Chrome running on Windows?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, push-notification

I usually work locally and in an RDP session 50/50. I've two Google Chromes launched locally and in the terminal session. I am tired of copying and pasting URLs back and forth. I thought abount making an extension for Chrome like the popular extension Chrome2phone. But after going into the details of how the Chrome2phone works I understand that there is possibly no such option as the push notification for a Chrome instance running on a usual desktop computer. Chrome2phone uses GCM to send/recieve messages. But GCM is only for Android devices..

Does anyone know if it is possible to implement push notifications between two Chromes running on different computer? I understand that this is a really weird question but nevertheless.. Maybe someone had this experience and can share it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is now. [Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome](http://developer.chrome.com/dev/apps/cloudMessaging.html).
I wonder if it can be made to work with Firefox or even a desktop application.

Comment: GCM for chrome will is built into the chrome application and maintains a connection to google servers, so you will not see this outside of chrome.  There are a few other solutions.  You can use the channel api on appengine and push messages from a server to another web client.  There is also webrtc.

Comment: I meant if the client protocol could be simulated so that any desktop app can use GCM.

Answer (score 2):

If you are logged into chrome, you can also solve this using Chrome Sync, using tab sync.  Just go to the new tab page, and look at "Other Devices" at the bottom, and you can see a tab that another computer is looking at, and go to it on this desktop.

Comment: Yeah, I use this feature. But I wanted a quicker solution. Because you have to wait for a little before the sync completes and then you will the open tabs in the chrome on another machine. If you know what I mean..